# Automated way to run bash script inside Ubuntu hosted in VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Windows 7 as host OS, and Ubuntu 14.04 as guest OS running under VirtualBox, I have some shared folders with data between Windows and Ubuntu and some binary in Ubuntu that do some processing of this data.

What I'm looking for if there is some way to run .bat script from Windows to run Ubuntu under VirtualBox (preferably in "silent" mode with no GUI) and run bash script inside Ubuntu to do processing then close VM.

Or

Manually run Ubuntu under VirtualBox once (preferably it should work in background with no GUI).
Run .bat script from Windows to run bash script inside Ubuntu to do processing.

Answer (score 1):

Your .bat Windows script could run VBoxManage commands to start and stop your Ubuntu VM using the "--type headless" argument.  And if you have an SSH client on your Windows box, you could call that from your Windows host to connect to the Ubuntu VM running whatever commands you want.